# Python define simple expression language (bash like)

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, unary-operator

I want to define my own simple language for evaluating literals.

Requirements:

- Based on python to allow easy use/addition of Python functions (not shown in the example)
- Token should be iterpreted as **Literal** if not preceded by `$`.
- `$` before token means it is a **Variable** (Similar to *bash*)

**TL;DR**:

I want `dollar_solution(**VAR_DICT)` to return `"Minimum Working Example"`

---

Due diligence (Ignore if not helpful):

- So far, I have been able to accomplish this but with the special character being Unary Subtraction (`USub` [`-`]).
- The part (of `dollar_solution`) that fails is during `ast.parse`. Looking at [the code for `ast.parse`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a8eb7372eebe182fd4ef7381a742d84a368a7d1b/Lib/ast.py#L34-L53), it just calls the `builtins:compile`. Does this mean I need to call my own compile with my own .asdl?
- Half-baked idea based on my research (in order of cleanliness):

  - Define unary operator `$` (in .asdl) and handle it in `MyTransormer::visit_UnaryOp`.
  - Define my own `.asdl` to allow dollar as a valid character in names and handle it in MyTransformer
- It smells like I might need to define my own language. Where do I start with that with a parser in Python?
- Is there some library that does that already?

```py
import ast
from _ast import Name, Constant, BinOp, Add, UnaryOp, USub
from typing import Any

EXPECTED_RESULT = "Minimum Working Example"

VAR_DICT = {"mini": "Minimum", "ex": "Example"}

MINUS_EXPRESSION = "-mini + ' ' + Working + ' ' + -ex"
DOLLAR_EXPRESSION = "$mini + ' ' + Working + ' ' + $ex"


def minus_solution(**kwargs):
    tree = ast.parse(MINUS_EXPRESSION, mode="eval")
    safe_tree = MyTransformer(var_dict=kwargs).visit(tree)
    return ast.literal_eval(safe_tree)


def dollar_solution(**kwargs):
    tree = ast.parse(DOLLAR_EXPRESSION, mode="eval")
    safe_tree = MyTransformer(var_dict=kwargs).visit(tree)
    return ast.literal_eval(safe_tree)


def main():
    try:
        assert dollar_solution(**VAR_DICT) == EXPECTED_RESULT
    except:
        print("Dollar Solution Failed!!!")
    else:
        print("Dollar Solution Success!!!")

    try:
        assert minus_solution(**VAR_DICT) == EXPECTED_RESULT
    except:
        print("Minus Solution Failed!!!")
    else:
        print("Minus Solution Success!!!")


class MyTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, var_dict):
        self._var_dict = var_dict

    def visit_Name(self, node: Name) -> Any:
        return Constant(
            value=node.id,
            col_offset=node.col_offset,
            lineno=node.lineno,
        )

    def visit_BinOp(self, node: BinOp) -> Any:
        super().generic_visit(node)
        assert (
            isinstance(node.op, Add)
            and isinstance(node.left, Constant)
            and isinstance(node.right, Constant)
        ), f"Bad operand or operator"

        return Constant(
            value=str(node.left.value) + str(node.right.value),
            col_offset=node.col_offset,
            lineno=node.lineno,
        )

    def visit_UnaryOp(self, node: UnaryOp) -> Any:
        assert isinstance(node.operand, Name) and isinstance(
            node.op, USub
        ), "Not Name in expression"
        return Constant(
            value=self._var_dict[node.operand.id],
            col_offset=node.col_offset,
            lineno=node.lineno,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, `ast` is specifically a *Python* parser, and `$` is not a valid token in Python's grammar. You need a tokenizer that recognizes `$`, and then define a grammar (which can be based on Python's) that can consumer DOLLAR tokens.